# Using select and option and remembering after POST

Tags: php, html

Using select and option HTML tags, I pass information through using $_POST.

When reloading the page however, the select resets back to the original values.
I am looking to get it to remember what has been passed through.

```
<?php
        foreach($data as $value => $title)
        {
            foreach($ag as $first) 
            {
                foreach($af as $second) 
                {
                    echo"<option value='$value-$first-$second'>$title - $first - $second</option>";
                }
            }
        }
        ?>
```

As you can see, I use 3 foreach loops to populate whats in it.
How can I achieve my selection being remembered?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: reloaded as in refreshed?  And how/what variables are being passed?  (Post is obvious - but what are the other variables... ?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use the name of your `select` field in place of "`your_select_field_name`" in my change below:

```
<?php
        foreach($data as $value => $title)
        {
            foreach($ag as $first) 
            {
                foreach($af as $second) 
                {
                    echo "<option value='$value-$first-$second'";
                    if( $_POST['your_select_field_name'] == "$value-$first-$second" ) {
                        echo ' selected="selected"';
                    }

                    echo ">$title - $first - $second</option>";
                }
            }
        }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The output for the selected option on the new page needs to look like:

```
<option value='foo' selected>...<option>
```

Comment: It should be `selected="selected"`

Answer (score 1):

HTML does not have memory. The item that's selected by default in a `<select>` form element is the one with the `selected` attribute (or the first one if none). Simply use the information contained in $_POST to generate the appropriate markup:

```
<select name="foo">
    <option value="v1">Label 1</option>
    <option value="v2">Label 2</option>
    <option value="v2" selected="selected">Label 3</option>
    <option value="v4">Label 4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the selected tag on the correct option. Something like this:

```
<?php
    $postedValue = $_POST['select_name'];
    foreach($data as $value => $title)
    {
       foreach($ag as $first) 
       {
           foreach($af as $second) 
           {
               $computedValue = $value . '-' . $first . '-'. $second;
               if ( $computedValue == $postedValue)  { 
                   $selected = "selected";
               } else { 
                   $selected = '' 
               }
               echo "<option value='$computedValue' $selected>$title - $first - $second</option>";
           }
       }
    }
    ?>
```

It could probably be written cleaner but this is the general idea.